# MongoDB Configuration File Locations

Tags: mongodb, configuration

Some databases search/check multiple locations for configuarion files, if it finds many, it merges and does a priority if same options defined.

Does mongodb search multiple locations for configuration files? (starting as a service, not using --config option)

From searching I know it checks `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` by default.

I am hoping to do is separate my global config and production/development config.

Comment: What O/S are you using, and how did you install MongoDB? I'm guessing OS X + Homebrew given the config file path.

Comment: Yes, OSX with homebrew. But, I don't think it is a system thing. Either mongodb has that functionality or not (unless at build time you can provide multiple paths for conf locations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The MongoDB server actually does *not* search any locations for config files, and there is (as at MongoDB 3.2) no way to specify multiple config files or include config file fragments. There was a feature suggestion for includes discussed (see: [SERVER-14911](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-14911) in the MongoDB issue tracker), but it was decided that includes are not part of standard YAML and configuration management systems are likely the best option.

> From searching I know it checks /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf by default.

This is the default provided in the service [recipe for the `mongodb` Homebrew package](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library%2FFormula%2Fmongodb.rb#L103). The official Linux packages generally use a convention of `/etc/mongod.conf`.

Comment: What is a configuration management system? (If you provide a name, to narrow the search)

Comment: @PrivatMamtora Some popular [open source configuration management systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_open-source_configuration_management_software) include Chef, Puppet, Ansible, and SaltStack but there are a lot of options available depending on your requirements. Full-blown configuration management solutions are likely overkill if you have a straightforward production environment and a small development team, but as the team/deployment grows these tools help you automate consistent deployments.